# conditional formatting - hightlight a cell

Tags: function, if-statement, conditional-formatting

Can anyone assist me regarding conditional formatting in google sheets? It's pretty simple, though I can't seem to get it to work, my goal is to highlight or color the cell green (AQ) if (AR) is Y and red if (AR) is N. The custom value I'm trying to use is =$AR="Y". Then I choose background color green; however, it's not working. Please assist me. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Neither AQ nor AR is a valid cell reference. Use AR1 or whatever cell you are relying on. Google's documentation is pretty good on the subject: [see here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

**Relative Reference Example**

The following example highlights each cell in the range AQ1:AQ11 green if "Y" or "y" is in the adjacent cell in column AR.

[image]

**Absolute Reference Example**

If I wanted every cell in the range AQ1:AQ11 to be colored green based only on the value of AR1, I would use =$AR$1="Y" as my formula instead.

[image]

Comment: Great thanks so much for your assistance I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer so others with similar questions can more easily find it.